# In a Rails app, what is the Rails Way to organize non-model utility classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm abstracting the payment gateway I'm using out a a Subscription class and into a PaymentGatewayApi class so that it can be easily changed in the future without touching models. My APIs are located in `app/api` which appears to be just fine as I only have a few of them (although I'll move them if someone smarter than me says I should).

In trying to write quality code and reducing my parameter calls, I need to make some simple utility classes. One of these is a `CreditCardCustomer` that can be instantiated in the `Subscription` model and then have the instance passed to the `PaymentGatewayApi`.

My question is, where should I put this class? Does it need to be in its own file, or can I put multiple classes in the same file? What is the best practice both for Ruby in general and Rails in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, where should I put this class?

Normally these classes lives in `\lib`. However, if you are planning to use these classes across your projects, you should consider create a gem for it (rails 3 have some [nice support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) for that), and maybe release it as open source?

> Does it need to be in its own file, or can I put multiple classes in the same file?

It is usual to have one class per file, but Ruby is not Java, so follow your heart. Try not put two big classes in the same file, for instance. You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440074/ruby-is-it-acceptable-to-put-more-than-one-class-in-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

`CreditCardCustomer` sounds like a model to me.  Even if it's not an ActiveRecord model, it belongs in `app/models` if it's a business/domain object.  If it really is a utility class, then by all means put it in `lib`.

Comment: I had just assumed that all models are ActiveRecord models. I just use this class to avoid passing a bunch of attributes around, ala Ben Orenstein-style refactoring. I have more important AR models that encapsulate all of its attributes, like Subscription and User. Based on my description and your experience, does this sound like a Utility class or a Domain Object?